# Rails has_and_belongs_to_many AND collection_check_boxes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

So there isn't an error, my join table just isn't being populated with any information... @lead.districts returns District::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy rather than the expected text...

Where have I made my mistake?

new.html.erb

```
<%= link_to("<< Back to List", {:action => 'index'}, :class => 'back-link') %>

<div class="subjects new">

  <h2>Create Lead</h2>

  <%= form_for(:lead, :url => {:action => 'create'}) do |f| %>

  <table cellspacing="0">
      <tr>
          <th>First Name</th>
          <td><%= f.text_field(:first_name) %></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <th>Last Name</th>
          <td><%= f.text_field(:last_name)%></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <th>Phone Number</th>
          <td><%= f.text_field(:phone_number)%></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <th>Email</th>
          <td><%= f.text_field(:email)%></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <th>Move-in Date</th>
          <td><%= f.date_field(:move_in_date, min: Date.today)%></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <th>Bedrooms</th>
          <td><%= f.text_field(:beds)%></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <th>Bathrooms</th>
          <td><%= f.text_field(:baths)%></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <th>Maximum Price Considered</th>
          <td><%= f.text_field(:maxprice)%></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <th>Preferred Neighborhoods</th>
          <td>
            <%= collection_check_boxes(:lead, :district_ids, District.all.order("districts.name ASC"), :id, :name )%>
          </td>

      </tr>
      <tr>
          <th>Have you ever broken a lease?</th>
          <td>
            <%= f.label :broken_lease, "Yes", :value => true %>
            <%= f.radio_button :broken_lease, true %>
            <%= f.label :broken_lease, "No", :value => false %>
            <%= f.radio_button :broken_lease, false %>
          </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <th>Have you ever been convicted of a felony?</th>
          <td>
            <%= f.label :felon, "Yes", :value => true %>
            <%= f.radio_button :felon, true %>
            <%= f.label :felon, "No", :value => false %>
            <%= f.radio_button :felon, false %>
          </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <th>Do you have any pets?</th>
          <td>
            <%= f.label :pets, "Yes", :value => true %>
            <%= f.radio_button :pets, true %>
            <%= f.label :pets, "No", :value => false %>
            <%= f.radio_button :pets, false %>
          </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <th>If so, please provide a brief description</th>
          <td><%= f.text_area(:pets_description)%></td>
      </tr>
  </table>

  <div class="form-buttons">
    <%= submit_tag("Create Lead") %>
  </div>

  <% end %>
</div>
```

leads_controller.rb

```
  class LeadsController < ApplicationController

  layout false

  def index
    @leads = Lead.order("leads.created_at DESC")
  end

  def show
    @lead = Lead.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @lead = Lead.new
    @districts = District.all.order("districts.name ASC")

  end

  def create
    @lead = Lead.new(lead_params)

    if @lead.save
      redirect_to(:action => 'index')
    else
      render('new')
    end

  end

  def edit
    @lead = Lead.find(params[:id])

  end

  def update
    @lead = Lead.find(params[:id])

    if @lead.update_attributes(lead_params)
      redirect_to(:action => 'show', :id => @lead.id)
    else
      render('edit')
    end
  end

  def delete
    @lead = Lead.find(params[:id])

  end

  def destroy
    lead = Lead.find(params[:id]).destroy
    flash[:notice] = "Lead '#{lead.id}' deleted successfully."
    redirect_to(:action => 'index')
  end

  private
    def lead_params
      params.require(:lead).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :phone_number, :email, :move_in_date, :beds, :baths, :maxprice, :broken_lease, :felon, :pets, :pets_description, :district => [])

    end


end
```

districts_controller.rb

```
class DistrictsController < ApplicationController

  layout false

  def index
    @districts = District.order("districts.name ASC")
  end

  def show
    @district = District.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @district = District.new
  end

  def create
    @district = District.new(district_params)

    if @district.save
      flash[:notice] = "District created successfully."
      redirect_to(:action => 'index')
    else
      render('new')
    end

  end

  def edit
    @district = District.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @district = District.find(params[:id])

    if @district.update_attributes(district_params)
      flash[:notice] = "District updated successfully."
      redirect_to(:action => 'show', :id => @district.id)
    else
      render('edit')
    end
  end

  def delete
    @district = District.find(params[:id])

  end

  def destroy
    district = District.find(params[:id]).destroy
    flash[:notice] = "District '#{district.name}' deleted successfully."
    redirect_to(:action => 'index')
  end


  private
    def district_params
      params.require(:district).permit(:name)

    end


end
```

district.rb

```
class District < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_and_belongs_to_many :leads

end
```

lead.rb

```
class Lead < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_and_belongs_to_many :districts

end
```

Join table migration:

```
class CreateDistrictsLeadsJoin < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :districts_leads, :id => false do |t|
      t.integer "district_id"
      t.integer "lead_id"
    end
    add_index :districts_leads, ["district_id", "lead_id"]
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My error was in mass assigning my params (used :district should have been :district_ids)

Correct params function:

```
# leads_controller.rb
  private
    def lead_params
      params.require(:lead).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :phone_number, :email, :move_in_date, :beds, :baths, :maxprice, :broken_lease, :felon, :pets, :pets_description, :district_ids => [])

    end
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add leads to district and districts to leads in both create methods.

```
def create # in LeadsController
    @lead = Lead.new(lead_params)

    if @lead.save
      district = District.find(...) #find district to associate
      district.leads << @lead #add lead to district 

      redirect_to(:action => 'index')
    else
      render('new')
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 #leads_controller.rb
 def create
    @lead = Lead.new(lead_params)

    if @lead.save 
     selected_dis = params['lead_district_ids'] #[3,4,5]
     districts = District.where(id: selected_dis).first
     #check how you getting district params and use that to fetch orders.
      districts.each do |d|
        @lead.districts << d 
        #assumming your one lead can have many districts.
      end
      redirect_to leads_path
    else
      render :new
    end

  end
```